# Begin This Section of Questioning Again

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a goofy little coding project. I am trying to use to learn C# and my problem is i am running into it but i don't know how to take the `default` and return it to the previous question to where it would have to ask the question again if user didn't input something that is a choice. I've tried loops, that i keep breaking, I've tried if/else and I've only been coding for a short time so this is pretty foreign for the most part. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Console.WriteLine("question blah blah blah");

string choice1 = "blah1";
string choice2 = "blah2";
string choice3 = "blah3";

string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

switch (userChoice)
{
  case "1":
    //Dostuff
  case "2":
    //Dostuff
  case "3":
    //Dostuff
  default:
    Console.WriteLine("you didn't enter something i could recognize")
    break 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `do-while` loop and a bool variable to control the execution.

```
bool loop;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("question blah blah blah");

    string choice1 = "blah1";
    string choice2 = "blah2";
    string choice3 = "blah3";

    string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

    // Set to false by default
    loop = false;

    switch (userChoice)
    {
        case "1":
            //Dostuff
            break;
        case "2":
            //Dostuff
            break;
        case "3":
            //Dostuff
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("you didn't enter something i could recognize");
            // Set to true to iterate again.
            loop = true;
            break;
    }
} while(loop);
```

Comment: does the while (loop) at the end tell it to go again? or does that just loop that one section beginning with do? sorry if this seems elementary, trying to understand the loop a bit better.

Comment: A `do-while` loop does something one time, and then repeats if a condition is true. In this case the variable `loop` is the conditional and is set to `true` if the `switch` hits the default case.

Comment: dude,  many thanks for the help,  i was on the right track with this but was super confused on how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome the SO community!

> Generally this code can be put in a `do-while` loop and a `flag` is set based on the user input which decides if user input is sought again or not - may be set it once before the switch assuming a happy case where user will make a valid choice, or in the default case where user will input something else. You may optionally clear the screen before you print the question.

Comment: thanks! that got me pointed in the right direction, ill look into this and see what i can come up with!